# How do I make a shortcut command in terminal?

Tags: terminal, command-line

I want to have `ll` as a shortcut for `ls -ll`. How can I add it to my Termianl application? I use *iTerm* as my primary Terminal application. I wish there was a single line command solution for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add it to your `.bash_profile` by running `nano ~/.bash_profile` and adding

```
alias ll='ls -ll'
```

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file.

Restart Terminal. `ll` should now be an alias for `ls -ll`. Use it like you would any other commands.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. In both native terminal app and iTerm. I was confused with all `bashrc` file locations.

Comment: @Mohsen Ah. That would do it. :-)

Comment: No need to restart the terminal, you can execute the same command on the shell `alias ll='ls -ll'` or source you `.bash_profile again` by `source ~/.bash_profile`.